# Exclude "No Value" in Spotfire Cross Table

Tags: spotfire

Is there any way to remove the **"--"**  (No Value) in the cross table. Instead of "---" I am trying to make it as blank? I am using a aggregation function. Appreciate your thoughts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Spotfire version 7.7+, you can configure what is displayed in the cross table for empty values via `Tools > Options > Cross Table > Display cells with no data as:` and put and empty string. Ref: [Spotfire forum](https://community.tibco.com/questions/empty-value-issue-cross-table).

Answer (score 0):

TIBCO has an enhancement request for this, but it's not high priority.

unfortunately there's no workaround other than inserting data into your data source that will evaluate to 0 instead of NULL.

Comment: Hi Niko, Thank you for the update. I think this will be nice, if we have a feature to display it as blank.

Comment: if you have a TIBCO support account, the best thing you can do is to request to be added to the enhancement request. sorry that I don't have a better answer :(